# Replacing a string with regex using replace module in Ansible

Tags: regex, replace, ansible

I need to replace a string with `app_name: <anything>` to `app_name: {{ node }}`.

There is some syntax error while tried to execute using the replace module below:

> replace: dest=/ABC/hybris/newrelic/newrelic.yml regexp='app_name:\s[A-Za-z0-9 ]*' replace='app_name: "{{ node }}"'

Error Message:

```
[ansible@dev-ci ansible]$ ansible-playbook -i hosts_acc ACC.yml --tags=newrelic
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/ABC/Ansible/roles/NewRelic_Base/tasks/main.yml': line 12, column 101, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- name: NewRelic - Replace app_name variable
  replace: dest=/ABC/hybris/newrelic/newrelic.yml regexp='app_name:\s[A-Za-z0-9 ]*' replace="app_name: {{ node }}"
                                                                                                    ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Comment: Instead of `replace`, you should use `template` and write the whole thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your example is the colon followed by a space inside the Ansible notation (with equal signs), so there are several ways to avoid it.

My advice is to use YAML syntax:

```
tasks:
  - replace:
      dest: ./src
      regexp: 'app_name:\s[A-Za-z0-9 ]*'
      replace: 'app_name: {{ node }}'
```

---

For ideas with Ansible notation see [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/2769).

Examples:

```
- replace: dest=./src regexp='app_name:\s[A-Za-z0-9 ]*' replace='app_name{{ ":" }} {{ node }}'
```

```
- replace: dest=./src regexp='app_name:\s[A-Za-z0-9 ]*' replace='app_name:{{ " " }}{{ node }}'
```

```
- replace: "dest=./src regexp='app_name:\s[A-Za-z0-9 ]*' replace='app_name: {{ node }}'"
```

Comment: Will this replace module work for windows remote servers? I couldnt see it mentioned in documentation. When I try, it shows error as- winrm send_input failed; \nstdout: Unable to initialize device PRN\r\n\nstderr ANSIBALLZ_WRAPPER. Please suggest.